# Create fix A4 size printable bootstrap 3 page?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using bootstrap 3 for frontend.I need to integrate functionality on my project that that generates report and then exports the report layout to A4 size pdf,prints the report and attach it to mail.I know css but I am noob on css print media feature,someone please provide me best tutorial sources regarding creating bootstrap 3 compatible printable page layout and way to export and print it?

Answer (score -1):

To create printable bootstrap 3 page. You will need to a stylesheet assigned for printing. Create the html file and style the printable page style in a seperate css file the add the following link to the html file.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="print" href="print.css">
or
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap.min.css">
or 
@media print {
 /* Your styles here */
}
```